# Interrupt ISR not triggering when using while loop

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, interrupt, esp32

I am using an interrupt to turn a flag to True when data is ready  from an external ADC. This interrupt is being triggered, however when I  add:

```
while(!dataReady);
```

to wait for the interrupt to change the flag True, the interrupt ISR function no longer triggers.
Here is my full code:

```
static volatile bool dataReady = false;

void dataReadyInterrupt()
{
  dataReady = true;
}

MCP3464::MCP3464()
{
  ch = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(dataReadyPin), dataReadyInterrupt, RISING); 
}

signed short MCP3464::read()
{
  // wait for interrupt to turn dataReady True before reading next adc conversion
  while(!dataReady);
  dataReady = false;
  // SPI full duplex transfer
  digitalWrite(adcChipSelectPin,LOW); 
  SPI.transfer(readConversionData);
  adcReading = (SPI.transfer(0) << 8);
  adcReading += SPI.transfer(0);
  digitalWrite(adcChipSelectPin, HIGH);

  ch++;
  
  if (ch >= numOfCh)
  {
    ch = 0;
  }

  // Write the new ADC channel to multiplexer
  writeData(&muxRegisters[ch][0], 2);

  // Start the next conversion (single conversion mode)
  writeData(&startConversionFastCmd, 1);
  
  return adcReading;
}
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: How `MCP3464::read()` is invoked? Not from an interrupt, I hope.

Comment: I don't see how this code would run without crashing on an ESP32. `while(!dataReady);` should trigger the watchdog timer and reset the ESP32 if it sits there for more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MCP3464::MCP3464()
{
  ch = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(dataReadyPin), dataReadyInterrupt, RISING); 
}
```

You are setting up the interrupt through the class constructor, for standard C++ Class, this is perfectly fine. However, for Arduino, although you didn't mention how and where you instantiate the Class instance. But if you create a instance before `setup()`, your constructor run, and the Arduino has not initializes all the pins assignments and the system init yet, you can see this in the [main](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L33-L51) function of Arduino Core.

It is why most of the Arduino library uses a `begin()` method to setup the library instance instead of using the class constructor as [Arduino Style Guide for Writing Libraries](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/APIStyleGuide) suggests to:

> Use begin() to initialize a library instance, usually with some settings. Use end() to stop it.

One more thing, I noticed that you are using `SPI.transfer()` without using the `SPI.beginTransaction()` and `SPI.endTransaction()`, this may works for single instance of SPI or if you only had one SPI device on the bus, but you might facing problem/issue when you have multiple instances/devices. For that, I would suggest you read my answer to another question [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/79760/40646).

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. This makes a lot of sense, it's annoying Arduino has slight nuances compared to traditional c++